# Inter application communication in apache spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have two applications : App1 and App2. 
On a single cluster I have to spawn 5 instances os App1 and 1 instance of App2.

What would be the best way to send data from the 5 App1 instances to the single App2 instance ?

Right now I am using Kafka to send data from one spark application to the spark application  but the setup doesn't seem right and I hope there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html) might be useful to you.

> Apache Ignite provides an implementation of Spark RDD abstraction
>   which allows to easily share state in memory across multiple Spark
>   jobs, either within the same application or between different Spark
>   applications.